# Problemas de localización con MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Estoy aprendiendo `meteor` y e instalado `mongodb` y `mongodb-tools` en Arch, en ese mismo orden.

Creo la aplicación `meteor` y cuando ejecuto el servidor esto es lo que me aparece:

```
[[[[[ /run/media/salahaddin/Datos/Proyectos/Cursos/blog ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.     
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.     
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.     
Can't start Mongo server.                     
MongoDB failed global initialization

Looks like MongoDB doesn't understand your locale settings. See
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4019 for more details.
```

Según la consulta que hice, tengo que cambiar la localización de mi sistema a `en_US`, pero no quiero hacer esto para evitar posibles conflictos dentro del sistema.

Con `Postgres` sólo se necesita inicializar la base de datos en la localización del sistema, pero no sé si esto se pueda hacer en `MongoDB`.

Esta es mi configuración local:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De no ser posible, con que otra base de datos puedo hacer trabajar `meteor`?

**Actualización:**
Solucionado, para ello, leyendo en el reporte del problema he visto que hay que generar los locales en inglés. Lo entendí bien, así que en la wiki de Arch encontre que se puede modificar el archivo `/etc/locale.gen`, descomentar la linea para inglés de USA, `en_US`, y luego volver a usar el comando `locale-gen` para generar los archivo en el idioma local y en el idioma inglés, y eso es todo.

Comment: ¿Tienes el locale generado siquiera? Es posible que con eso baste.

Comment: Que locale tienes configurado actualmente?

Comment: tengo es_CO, no entiendo que quiere decir si lo tengo generado,  si voy a la carpeta locales, creo que si lo tengo.

Comment: @Darkhogg, si, ya lo generé, ayer lo generé localmente nuevamente y sigo teniendo el mismo problema con meteor, que puedo hacer?

Comment: @SalahAdDin Deberías añadir esa última actualización como respuesta y marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver este problema se debe generar los archivos locales para el idioma inglés de Estados Unidos.

Primero editamos el archivo `locale-gen`: `sudo nano /etc/locale.gen`
Luego descomentamos el código correspondiente al inglés de Estados Unidos: `en_US`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Podemos ver que tenemos el idioma local y el idioma inglés, guardamos y cerramos.
Luego ejecutamos el comando `locale-gen` y ya está. Esto generará los archivos de localización para inglés y español, los de inglés son los necesarios para que mongoDB pueda ejecutarse.

Comment: Buena respuesta